# Validate HTML and CSS for all files in Visual Studio project

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, editor

I have an ASP.NET MVC website project in Visual Studio 2012. When I open an HTML or CSS file, the editor will create a warning if some of the HTML/CSS is invalid according to the HTML/CSS specification.

Is there a way to show warnings for *all* HTML/CSS files in the entire project without having to open each individual file?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You can open all the HTML files at once and correct all the validation errors. You need to do this only once; after that the only new validation errors that can be introduced are the ones HTML files you are changing in the editor anyway.

Comment: The problem is that I have hundreds of HTML files and a lot of them were originally made in an earlier version of Visual Studio that did not validate the files. Therefore, I am simply asking if there is a way to check the entire project without having to open every single file. There is already a way of checking for compliance with the [accessibility standards](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag.php) so why not the HTML and CSS standards? (maybe I should "just" write a plugin myself)